# How to restore input file type field after failling form validation in cakephp

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have a form :

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post',array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('name');    
echo $this->Form->input('image',array('label'=>'Image','type'=>'file','accept'=>'image/png,image/jpeg')); 

echo $this->Form->end();
```

When I submit the form and validation fails, the name field gets restored the value but image field becomes empty.

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842571/can-you-re-populate-file-inputs-after-failed-form-submission-with-php-or-javascr

Comment: @Sojtin. How can I get the file path in a hidden field after validation falis.