# Input::old for Form::file in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this form that includes a `Form::file` along with other form stuff. say for example a `Form::select` what I'm trying to do is to retain the file inside the `Form::file` when the user made a mistake say for example the user did not entered a value for the `Form::select`.as of now i have this code, I tried to add the `Input::old` to my `Form::file` here is the code

```
{{ Form::file('cascUpload' , Input::old('cascUpload'), 
  array('id' => 'cascUpload' , 'type' => 'file' , 
 'accept' => '.doc , .docx , .pdf , .ppt , .pptx , .xlsx , .xls , .csv , .txt' )) 
}}
```

but it is not working. any ideas on what is wrong with my code? or on how I can improve it? thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Short answer "no". Long answer "yes" with a "but". Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6842674/5912664.

Answer (score 0):

If your form is using blade template and you have some kind of validation in your controller then you can redirect user back with all values inserted/selected just by using `withInput()` in your controller.

```
return Redirect('page_url')->withInput();
```

See more in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#old-input)