# How to retain file input value after form submission with errors?

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, postback

I have what seems to be a rather basic question and wanted to confirm how best to deal with it. I have a form with a number of inputs one of which is a file input. On submission of the form there are a number of validation checks in PHP to confirm all necessary fields have been filled out as they should have been (and if not then it notifies the user to fill out the remainder and shows them the form again without submitting it). This is all fine but if a user has selected a file then i don't believe there's anyway of keeping the selected file within the input due to browser security settings.

As a result the only way i can see to keep the file input is to either store it on the server on  initial submission (even if the other fields aren't complete) and then associate this with the submission when it's submitted correctly. Or to use Javascript to validate the form so it isn't actually submitted until it's completed (so the file input doesn't ever need to be set programatically).

Am I missing something here and there's another way of dealing with this or am i right in saying these are the only two options?

Thanks guys!

Dave

Comment: You can also submit form by AJAX, I guess, but I'd like to see some other ideas as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restoring the value of a input type=file after failed validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205634/restoring-the-value-of-a-input-type-file-after-failed-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you already suggested the answer to your problem . it owuld be better to validate other fields of the form using ajax and don't submit the file initially. anbd if you have some problems with the file you can have some basic checks for your file using like file extension using ajax

Comment: The only problem with using JS/AJAX to validate is that if the user has JS turned off them this will not work (although we can have PHP validation as a fallback). That's why i was wondering if there was any alternative (other than storing the file initially and reassociating it when the form is successfully submitted)