# set_value not work on input type file on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using HMVC Codeigniter pattern for my project. And In my project I need to set the value on form where input type of field is file.So, I feel greatful for them who help me to solve out this problem.

My controller is test.php

```
<?php
class Test extends Controller{
function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  

    }
function index(){

redirect('test/form');


}
  function form(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name','required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mname','Middle Name','required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Last Name','required|trim');


        if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Attach Your File', 'required');
        }
        if($this->form_validation->run($this)){

                    $_SESSION['msg']="Your form has been submitted succesfully!!";
                    redirect('test/form');
                }
                else
                {

                    $_SESSION['err']="Opp! There was some wrong to fill up a form so try again!!!";
                    redirect('test/form');


                }

            }
        $data['pgtitle']='Test';       
        $this->load->view('test',$data);
        } 
}
```

My view file is test.php

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url()?>test/form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">


    <tr>
      <td width="">Name</td>
      <td width="158"><label for="fname"></label>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" class='input-row' value="<?php echo set_value('fname')?>"/><span class="required"><?php echo form_error('fname');?></span></td>
      <td width="158"><label for="mname"></label>
      <input type="text" name="mname" id="mname" placeholder="Middle Name" class='input-row' value="<?php echo set_value('mname')?>"/></td>
      <td width="158"><label for="lname"></label>
      <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" class='input-row' value="<?php echo set_value('lname')?>"/><span class="required"><?php echo form_error('lname');?></span></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Attach Your File</td>
      <td colspan="2"><label for="userfile"></label>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="usefile" value="<?php echo set_value('userfile')?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo form_error('userfile')?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="Button" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form >
```

Comment: you can not, due to security purposes. imagine a browser crawling your filesystem ! [ref1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205634/restoring-the-value-of-a-input-type-file-after-failed-validation) [ref2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html). you may use other workarounds to repopulate item name in a text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set_value` will not work because your are redirecting `redirect('test/form');` when the validation fails. you have to load `form view` without redirection than it will work.

`if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I am finding it to be impossible to populate the

```
<input type='file />
```

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)